# iOS dropbox sdk / core api - listing public folder contents without authorization

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I've tried checking on stackoverflow and on the api docs, but couldn't find any info pertaining to this particular question.

What I'm trying to do is getting the public folder contents of a particular dropbox account (like the /metadata function of the api), without the need to authorize/link to dropbox.
I know "/metadata/link" allows you to get metadata of a particular link without user authorization, but I couldn't find a way to get regular metadata and file listing...

Actually it doesn't even need to be a public folder (as I've read recently that dropbox discourages developers regarding relying on public folders for apps), it can just as well be a regular folder through its shared link or anything of the kind...

I'm using api v1 (but can consider changing to v2 if this is impossible with v1), although I'm not even sure if this is at all possible.

Thank you!

Comment: "I know '/metadata/link' allows you to get metadata of a particular link without user authorization, but I couldn't find a way to get regular metadata and file listing..." Could you describe what you want that's not provided by `/metadata/link`?

Comment: @smarx actually I haven't been able to test /metadata/link, as I can't seem to find anywhere any example code for accessing it... I've been using [[self restClient] loadMetadata:path]; for accessing folder metadata, but that only works for root-relative folders

Comment: I don't think `/metadata/link` is implemented in the v1 iOS Core SDK, so you'd have to add support yourself. But I think it does what you want.

Comment: Aww damn... Is it on the v2 swift one? I'd consider switching to swift just for that >_>

Comment: I believe it is, but adding the method yourself to the v1 SDK is probably not too hard either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, if anyone needs this as well, here's how I did it:

```
NSString *parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?link=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@",fileUrl, appKey, appSecret];
NSString *sharedPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",@"https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/link", parameters];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sharedPath];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                      timeoutInterval:10];
theRequest.timeoutInterval = 5.0;
theRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSData * resData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Use NSJSONSerialization to parse resData and refer to the api documentation for json fields, and that's it.

For the sake of simplicity showing it here I used synchronous request, but it can just as easily be done with asynchronous connection delegates.